# SSIS - Using flat file as a Parameter/Variable

Tags: variables, parameters, ssis, flat-file

I would like to know how to use a flat file (with only one value, say datetime) as a Parameter/Variable. Instead of feeding a SQL query value from Edit SQL task into a variable I want to save them as a flat file and then load them again as a Parameter/Variable.

Comment: `Instead of feeding a SQL query value from Edit SQL task into a variable I want to save them as a flat file and then load them again as a Parameter/Variable.` why?

Comment: I know it's unnecessary but it's a requirement in what I'm doing @BhupeshC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using Script Task .

1 Set ReadonlyVeriable  == file name

2 select  ReadWriteveriable name   = Variablename you have to populate.

3 Script write logic to find the value ( read file and get value)
set the value

```
      this.Dts.Variables("sFileContent").Value = StreamText ;
```